# Pulling up a parent model: undefined method `title' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am working on a test site built mostly with scaffolding. The problem I am facing is trying to access a parent model through the child model. Here is what is in my view that I am trying to pull up:

```
= @page.unit.title
```

This snippet is in my views/pages/show.html.haml.

As you can see I have a page that belongs to a unit. I am trying to pull up the name of the unit it is associated with. This is however not working and is giving me the error listed in the title. Here is what is in the page model:

```
class Page < ApplicationRecord
    extend FriendlyId
    belongs_to :unit, class_name: "Unit", foreign_key: "parent_id"
    friendly_id :title, use: :slugged
  acts_as_taggable
end
```

How do I pull up the name of the unit through the page.

Comment: The error is self-explanatory. Check if `@page.unit` is initialized.

Comment: It isn't. How would you do that through the model?

Comment: I think `parent_id` is nil on your database and also it should be `belongs_to :unit, foreign_key: 'parent_id'`

Comment: @Jakxna360 you need to assign a `unit` to the `@page`. Either create a new object of `Unit` class, or find one in the DB, and then assign it as `@page.unit = your_object`

Comment: Thank you so much rails_id. the parent_id was blank for the record. Adding the page to a unit fixed the issue. You rock man : )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`parent_id` was nil. Adding the page to a unit fixed the issue.

Thank you rails_id for all of your help.